# How can I select all elements except a specific class and its descendants?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS, how can I select all elements except a specific class and its descendants?

For example, I want to select all elements except `.my-class` and its descendants in the code below. I tried `:not(.my-class *)` but it doesn't work.

In my project there are many complicated global styles and it's hard to fix them all. So  I can't edit all these styles as @Michael_B has answered. I just want to do not apply these styles in `.my-class` and its descendants without making big changes.

```
<div>
  <span>a</span>
  <div>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
  <div class="my-class">
    <span>c</span>
    <div>
      <span>d</span>
      <div>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The compatibility of `not` selector can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp What browsers that you are targeting are not supported?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS alone, and before browser implementation of [Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/), I would say you need multiple selectors:

```css
*:not(.my-class) {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.my-class * {
  color: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>a</span>
  <div>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>
  <div class="my-class">
    <span>c</span>
    <div>
      <span>d</span>
      <div>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this solution I have to set default styles of `.my-class`. Is there an other way to do this without setting default styles to its attributes?

Comment: Consider posting a complete example (with both CSS and HTML). We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your class display to none by css. If you wish to show them again, change the display to block.

```
<style>
.my-class{
      display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually cant. What you can do is select all, select the class and select class descendents.

```
*{/*styles that will be for all elements except the class and its descendents*/}

.class, .class *{/*reversing styles applied before*/}
```